# bluetooth issues after upgrade to 21.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, mouse, 21.10

I have the following bluetooth issues after upgrading to 21.10 - there were no issues running 21.04 (Ubuntu standard desktop with Gnome).

**Sound quality for HFP**
When I switch from HiFi to Headseat mode there is a constant crackle, which makes it quite hard to follow a conversation. However that crackle disappears if I switch back to HiFi mode.
Headset: HyperX-Cloud Mix

**Mouse disconnects/reconnects**
My mouse radomly disconnects and reconnects whilst using it. Which is especially annoying when playing a game. But also other actions like scrolling in webbrowser are affected.
Mouse: Logitec Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535

Any hints how to resolve this?

Comment: ryzen 5 Dell inspirion ubuntu gnome 21.10 wayland; and newly paired devices drop connection and will no longer connect for me.  I have not tried booting into x11 but even if that solved the solution, that would not be a solution for me as I am tied to Wayland.

Comment: possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375207/how-do-i-get-bluetooth-to-workubuntu-21-10

Comment: possible solution checking now https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/q8u0nn/bluetooth_headphones_stopped_working_after/