# How do I get bluetooth to work(Ubuntu 21.10)?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, lenovo, 21.10

I am new to Linux. I have a problem with bluetooth. The headset keeps disconnecting after a few seconds of connection. Also with audio system 5.1 "Dialog". I can't transfer files from my phone (although I don't really need this feature, just to test the system). How do I get bluetooth to work?
Ubuntu 21.10, Lenovo IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming, Gnome version 40.4.0

Commands:

`systemctl | grep -i blue`

`dmesg | grep -i blue`

`lspci`

`bluetoothctl`

`rfkill list all`

`lsusb`

1 command output:

```
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d14-1\x2d14:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device       loaded    active plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                              loaded    active plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0
  bluetooth.service                                                                        loaded    active running   Bluetooth service
  bluetooth.target                                                                         loaded    active active    Bluetooth
```

2 command

```
[    2.470919] usb 1-14: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    5.008234] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.008302] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.008324] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.008333] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.008354] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.144936] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    5.145943] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    5.145948] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    5.377606] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    5.380594] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 31990
[    5.853994] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x829a7644
[   11.964450] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.964454] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.964459] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.200317] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.200325] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.200330] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  259.058704] traps: bluetooth[10701] trap divide error ip:7f6da086c440 sp:7f6da8d1bc30 error:0 in module-bluez5-device.so[7f6da086a000+9000]
[  297.394771] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
```

3 command

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake H] (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Lite-On Technology Corporation Device 9100 (rev 03)
07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

4 command

```
Agent registered
```

5th command

```
[bluetooth]# rfkill list all
Invalid command in menu main: rfkill

Use "help" for a list of available commands in a menu.
Use "menu <submenu>" if you want to enter any submenu.
Use "back" if you want to return to menu main.
```

execute 5th from new tab of terminal:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

6 command:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc SunplusIT Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 258a:0024 SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is your desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, MATE, Xfce)?

Comment: Gnome version 40.4.0

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my Dell inspirion Ryzen 5 .  Same version of Gnome Ubuntu and Wayland.  Tried connecting Bluetooth earpeice and speaker.  Same problem with both.  Connection for a second and then drops and then will not reconnect.  I have connected these devices to this computer when it was running 20.04 with no problems.

Comment: possible duplicate question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372849/bluetooth-issues-after-upgrade-to-21-10

Comment: possible solution checking now https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/q8u0nn/bluetooth_headphones_stopped_working_after/

Comment: I've tried those above solutions as well as this page https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-bluetooth-connectivity-issues-in-ubuntu/ and nothing works.  Very irritated.  Trying to load the bluetooth module says that it cannot connect `Module module-bluetooth-discover not loaded
`

Comment: Please run the following commands
① `systemctl | grep -i blue`
② `dmesg | grep -i blue`
③ `lspci`
④ `bluetoothctl`
⑤ `rfkill list all`
⑤ `lsusb`
And report the output of each

Comment: @JoshuaRobison , solutions from reddit and makeuseof.com not works. I added the output of the commands to the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue of JBL speaker disconnecting after a few seconds once I upgraded to 21.10 on my ASUS VivoBook S14.

Removing the device from bluetooth settings dialogue and adding again worked for me (earlier I was trying connect as device was listed)

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting the bluetooth driver

> sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

Comment: It did not  work

Comment: Try with "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo service bluetooth restart"